# i18n support on V8 with c++ wrapper file

Tags: javascript, internationalization, v8, icu, dayjs

In a project i am working we use V8 to execute javascript. There are v8lib_monolith.a files ( which suggest that v8 engine is pre compiled) . In the cmakelists which i am using to build my project i am linking my runtime with the v8 monolith library too. I also have a wrapper around this v8 where i am initalizing ICU. Still i am getting error when trying to use a function which utilised ICU library. the error call stack is:

```
stack: 'ReferenceError: Intl is not defined\n' + ' at getDateTimeFormat (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:24:5)\n' + ' at makeFormatParts (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:51:15)\n' + ' at tzOffset (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:56:24)\n' + ' at Function.d.tz (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:163:26)\n'
```

One possible reason i thought was if i build my V8 with

```
V8_ENABLE_I18N_SUPPORT=false
```

in args.gn file will initalizing the icu using

```
v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(path to lib file)
```

enable the ICU support.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually ask a question. Presumably you want to know how to get an `Intl` object?

With `v8_enable_i18n_support = false` in your `args.gn`, you get no `Intl` object. So either drop that arg (to use the default value, which is `true`), or explicitly set it to `true` if you prefer.

You need to initialize the location of the ICU data file *in addition to* enabling compile-time support for i18n.

Frankly, I'm not sure what `V8_ENABLE_I18N_SUPPORT=false` (in upper-case spelling) does. Based on the fact that you don't have an `Intl` object, I guess the variable name is case-insensitive. To make things clearer, why not spell it the official way, which is lower-case?